# Why did the Hunter x Hunter manga go on hiatus?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I think the *Hunter x Hunter* manga has been on hiatus for months now; does anyone know the reason for the hiatus? Is the author planning to continue the series?

Comment: Related: [Is there any news about Hunter x Hunter since June 2016?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/33877)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the past, the reasons cited for HxH hiatuses have usually been "ill health", "research", and "mangaka circumstances". Most of it, however, is said to fall under "mangaka circumstances". [This site](http://hunter.noihjp.com/rest/rest.php?Year=2013) (jp) tracks all of them.

Seeing as to how HxH and *Yu Yu Hakusho* have been such hits, the mangaka, [Yoshihiro Togashi](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=creator&creatorid=874), has gained a fair bit of clout at Shonen Jump and the editors are apparently very lenient with him. While it is said that he did suffer from health issues thanks to the pressing schedule of YYH, it is also said that he plays truant a lot and attends Comikets when he's supposedly sick. Togashi is also known to be a massive [Dragon Quest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Quest) (related [April Fool's joke](http://www.capsulecomputers.com.au/2013/04/hunter-x-hunter-returning-from-hiatus-togashi-checks-out-of-rehab/)) fan and apparently likes to take a break whenever a new version comes out.

The story goes that the mangaka does not like using assistants and prefers to draw everything himself. He is infamous for not meeting his weekly deadlines and releasing chapters with extremely rough artwork. He has been known for going on hiatus in order to redraw such chapters for release in the more lucrative [tankōbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank%C5%8Dbon) market.

I  can't find any source stating exactly why he is on hiatus now, but I think it's safe to assume that Togashi will be back and that the manga will continue. Only time will tell when this will happen.

Comment: You can also note that the quality goes up and down, and REAALLY down durring the ant arc, I assumed it was because he broke his hand or got carpel tunnel or something..

Comment: @ton.yeung Good point. I believe he redraws them for the tankōbons.

Comment: i think the answer need to be update