# Why did the Hunter x Hunter anime stop in episode 148?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

The Hunter X Hunter anime stopped in episode 148. I wonder why?

Is it because Hunter x Hunter is already finished?

Comment: I would wager a guess that they didn't want to continue producing it with the fact that the next chapter isn't complete and Togashi is too busy going on hiatus to actually write anything new.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hunter X Hunter Anime is not yet done. According to Togashi, he says he's on hiatus and that he's eventually continuing but the demand from the manga company is too much stress for him and he doesn't want to continue. The quota he has to fill is a chapter a week which is a lot for anyone in the manga industry.

From [a blog post by AlyZoldyck](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:AlyZoldyck/Rumors_about_Hunter_x_Hunter_manga_has_already_end.) on Hunter X Hunter Wikia.

Comment: Please keep in mind this Twitter account is not official or anything. He *says* his information is coming from interviews and such, but provides no sources.

Comment: @キルア - yes, and if the time stamp is correct: the wikia post was made on March 11, 2014. This is not up to date as the latest manga hiatus was last August and HxH anime episode 148 was last September.

Answer (score 8):

As what Miramiel stated, the mangaka of Hunter X Hunter, Togashi Yoshihiro is on an *indefinite* hiatus but will be back eventually.

However, it is worth nothing that the reason behind this hiatus is the mangaka's **illness**. Togashi has been experiencing serious back problems 
(sources: [FANDOM](http://www.fandompost.com/2014/09/05/yoshihiro-togashi-extends-hunter-x-hunter-manga-hiatus/), [ANN-1](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-09-04/hunter-hunter-manga-hiatus-continues-until-further-notice/.78384), [ANN-2](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-08-28/hunter-x-hunter-manga-extends-hiatus-at-least-1-more-week/.78119))
which have caused him numerous *short* breaks over the years. This illness (along with chest pains and sleep loss) has been with him for a quite a while and may have started back when he was still doing [Yuyu Hakusho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YuYu_Hakusho)

These back problems, particularly in the lower back area - makes it hard for a mangaka to deliver weekly chapters. When this condition worsened this year, he was forced to take a hiatus. The **anime** will not progress with the mangaka's storyline nor will it be filled with *fillers* because Togashi would not allow it (and frankly, it would be a waste). It is also [rumored](http://www.reddit.com/r/HunterXHunter/comments/2hdxi8/why_cant_yoshihiro_togashi_dictate_what_happens/) that Togashi could just ask an assistant/s to draw Hunter X Hunter with his storyline but chooses not to for various reasons.

You can read this related (old) question here for more links: [Why did the Hunter x Hunter manga go on hiatus?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4751/why-did-the-hunter-x-hunter-manga-go-on-hiatus)?